# How to create a table using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm newbie in XSL and XML. I tried to make a table which contain Name and ID that can generate into html file, but when I try to run it there's no output.

Here's my xml code:

```
  <Column Description="POS Name"/>

  <Column Description="POS ID"/>

</Columns>

<Row>

  <POS Name>Mall 1</POS Name>

  <POS ID>00001</POS ID>

</Row>

<Row>

  <POS Name>Mall 2</POS Name>

  <POS ID>00002</POS ID>

</Row>

<Row>
  <POS Name>Mall 3</POS Name>

  <POS ID>00003</POS ID>

</Row>
```

And here's my xsl code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://homecredit.net/homerselect/ws/incomingPayments/dto" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" standalone="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:element name="POS">
         <xsl:attribute name="lang">en</xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:element name="head">
            <xsl:element name="title">POS</xsl:element>
         </xsl:element>
         <xsl:element name="table">
            <xsl:attribute name="border">1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="tr">
               <xsl:element name="th">POS NAME</xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="th">POS ID</xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="tr">
               <xsl:element name="td">Mall</xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="td">00001</xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="tr">
               <xsl:element name="td">Mall 2</xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="td">00002</xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="tr">
               <xsl:element name="td">Mall 3</xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="td">00003</xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
         </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The final output that I need is like this

```
POS Name                 POS ID
Mall                     00001
Mall 2                   00002
Mall 3                   00003
```

Comment: How are you actually 'running' your XSLT, and where are you expecting it to be output?

Comment: And what is your input xml file. The xslt "expects" an xml containing a POS tag with lang, head attrs etc.

Comment: My expected output is like this Column 1 contains POS name under POS name are Mall, Mall 2, Mall 3 while column 2 contains POS ID under POS ID are 00001, 00002, 00003

Comment: Rephrasing Tim C's questions.  What application are you using to execute the XSLT?

Comment: I'm using wnscp as server

Answer (score 2):

See http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTutorial/Output/

XSLT is used to transform one XML doc into another. For this it matches portions of input and sends selected portions to the output, operating on them if needed.

If you have no input, use a dummy file containing `<dummy/>` and the following xslt for starters :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <head>
        <title>POS</title>
        </head>
        <table>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On my unix based system this gives :-

```
% xsltproc test.xslt in.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<head><title>POS</title></head><table/>
```

Comment: I need output like this POS Name                 POS ID
                        Mall                     00001
                        Mall 2                   00002
                        Mall 3                   00003